# We have been working with ListView for displaying my VERY LONG list (10,000 approx) items having Text + Image content. React native

Tags: react-native

React Native Community,

React-Native : 0.55.4
React: 16.4.1
Node: v8.11.1

Background:

We have been  working with ListView for displaying my VERY LONG list (10,000 approx) items having Text + Image content. But soon we bumped into optimization problem. After reading many blogs and other online material (Official + Non-Official), they all pointed towards the React Native optimized  FlatList. Things seemed well for us, however, we couldn’t  have been more wrong.

Problem:
FlatList solved the memory issues for us but more problems aroused.

View goes blank (white empty space) for a long time while scrolling at up or down at high speed
The Touch event takes a very long time to fire

What we have tried:

Increasing the windowSize to a higher number somewhat solves the empty white view while scrolling at high speed but has a huge memory size
Below is our flat list code we have tried to tweek a number of options but only some luck at memory optimization and completely no luck at solving the (hard) Touchable event (it takes long or many taps to fire)

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data1}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => <ReccomendationsItem key={index} homeFeedObj={item} isLogin={this.state.isLogin} />}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
  ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
  refreshing={this.state.refreshing1}
  onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
  onEndReached={this.handLoadMore}
  onEndThreshold={100}
  numColumns={2}
  windowSize={100}
  removeClippedSubviews={false}
  maxToRenderPerBatch = {1}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey there, I'm not knowledgeable about `react-native` but I was wondering; that's a lot of items in a list view. You also said you ran into memory issues before and now you don't. Perhaps this FlatList renders JIT or pools list items for reuse? That would explain why you now have less memory issues but more trouble getting the content to load. Would it therefore be possible to implement an item pooling system so you can continue to use a ListView? This would allow you to save memory and use the list view as before.

Comment: You should probably not try to render all 10k items and return new ones from the backend while scrolling. If that is not an option then check to see if the component you are giving your flatlist can be optimized. By either using shouldComponentUpdate or making it a pure component.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few optimizations you can try:

1. Experiment with `viewabilityConfig` so that you **don't** render all of the items while you're skipping by them at high speed. If the user is really going wild with scrolling the list and you're trying to render and cache all of the images and sub-components then it's going to slow down.
2. If your list items are a fixed size, or can be calculated easily, make sure your `FlatList` includes the `getItemLayout` prop. It will reserve space in the list for your items while they're loading which reduces the jumpiness of the `FlatList`.
3. Ensure that your list items have `shouldComponentUpdate` implemented or are PureComponents. Otherwise, a meaningless change to the item props could trigger a re-render of all the items and make your list unresponsive in the meantime.

Comment: how to dynamic row fix size

Comment: i tried every thing but still memory issue .
        this.viewabilityConfig = {
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 20,
            minimumViewTime: 1,
        };

Comment: <FlatList
                        data={this.state.data1}
                        renderItem={({ item, index }) => <ReccomendationsItem key={index} data={item}/>}

                        getItemLayout={(data, index) => {return { length: 10, offset: 10 * index, index }}}
                        onEndReached={this.handLoadMore}
                        onEndThreshold={100}
                        keyExtractor={index) => index}
                    />

Comment: You might try increasing `minimumViewTime` to something like 200, as it's in milliseconds. Also, try to simplify the `RecommendationsItem` component if possible since if it's doing a lot of calculations on each item it could be causing the memory issues.